# Is there any Java application code that is connecting to Azure Data Factory using Azure Java SDK?

Tags: java, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-java-sdk

I need to write a java application code using Azure Java SDK, to connect to Azure Data Factory to run the pipeline, to get the status of pipeline and to cancel the pipeline. I need a sample code for this.

I am new to Azure Java SDK. I need a sample java application code that connects to Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory has management REST APIs and language specific SDKs for for the APIs. So, you could use the SDK or call the APIs using Java to do the operations that you have mentioned.
For e.g. to start run of a pipeline you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/create-run?view=rest-datafactory-2018-06-01&tabs=Java).